# C# - Check DataAdapter state

Tags: c#, dataadapter

my title of question is probably wrong and don't be mad for It, but please let me explain what is my problem.

First, I have created a stored procedure which executes Insert/Update or Delete from my databound DatagridView, all together. This is done by passing different parameter values to my stored procedure in my TableAdapter setting of InsertCommand/UpdateCommand/DeleteCommand. Currently I solve this like this:

```
 private void InicializeAdapter()
 {
     da = new OracleDataAdapter();
     OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(conn_string);
     conn.Open();

     OracleCommand select = new OracleCommand("MySelectProcedure", conn);
     OracleCommand ins_upd = new OracleCommand("MyProcedure", conn);
     OracleCommand delete_rec = new OracleCommand("MyProcedure", conn);

     select.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
     ins_upd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
     delete_rec.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

     ins_upd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("ID_IN", OracleDbType.Decimal, 4, "ID"));
     ins_upd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("DELETE_IN", OracleDbType.Decimal)).Value = 0;
     ins_upd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("SERIAL_IN", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 50, "SERIAL"));

     delete_rec.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("ID_IN", OracleDbType.Decimal, 4, "ID"));
     delete_rec.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("DELETE_IN", OracleDbType.Decimal)).Value = 1;
     delete_rec.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("SERIAL_IN", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 50, "SERIAL"));

     da.SelectCommand = select;
     da.UpdateCommand = ins_upd;
     da.InsertCommand = ins_upd;
     da.DeleteCommand = delete_rec;

     da.MissingSchemaAction = MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey;
     conn.Close();
  }
```

In short, when I insert or update I send parameter "DELETE_IN"=0 to Oracle, and value "1" when I delete row from DatagridView. This way Oracle knows what to do, and my code works fine....

My question is - How could I only pass different values of that parameter based on what change has occured INSTEAD of writing all parameters again for DeleteCommand as you see in my example above ? I was thinking of something like a check If there is an Insert/Update or DeleteCommand, something like:

```
If (dataAdapter1.InsertCommand)
{
  ins_upd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("DELETE_IN", OracleDbType.Decimal)).Value = 0;
}
else if(dataAdapter1.Deletecommand)
{
 ins_upd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("DELETE_IN", OracleDbType.Decimal)).Value = 0;
}
```

I'm asking because this would shorten my code a lot. I know that changes can be monitored in DataTable, but I don't know how to use It when I assign commands for my DataAdapter.

Any help appreciated, thanks in advance !

P.S.: My Datagridview is bound to BindingSource, and datasource of BindingSource is Datatable.

Comment: Your second code sample does not compile. `if (dataAdapter1.InsertCommand)` does not work in C#.

Comment: @Sefe, ofcourse It doesn't, that was just a figurative speaking of what I need to solve my problem. I would need to know when DataAdapter chooses to execute insert,update or delete command, in order to pass my parameter value to Oracle correctly. That is my question.

Comment: It is not clear what you want to achieve with `if (dataAdapter1.InsertCommand)`. The condition is not boolean and it's an open guess what condition you want to check for. The purpose of the `if` is unclear to me, because the adapter will choose the right command automatically. And the bodies of the `if` and the `else` are identical. I'd recommend you describe your intended solution in text, because I have a hard time understanding it from the code sample, whether it compiles or not.

Answer (score 0):

A method call will solve your problem:

```
private static OracleCommand CreateUpdateDeleteCommand(OracleConnection connection,
    bool shouldDelete) {

    OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand("MyProcedure", connection);
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("ID_IN", OracleDbType.Decimal, 4, "ID"));    
    command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("DELETE_IN", OracleDbType.Decimal)).Value =
        shouldDelete ? 1 : 0;
    command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("SERIAL_IN", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 50,
        "SERIAL"));
    return command;
}

private void InitializeAdapter() {
    da = new OracleDataAdapter();
    OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(conn_string);
    conn.Open();

    OracleCommand select = new OracleCommand("MySelectProcedure", conn);
    select.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    da.SelectCommand = select;

    da.UpdateCommand = CreateUpdateDeleteCommand(conn, shouldDelete: false);
    da.InsertCommand = CreateUpdateDeleteCommand(conn, shouldDelete: false);
    da.DeleteCommand = CreateUpdateDeleteCommand(conn, shouldDelete: true);

    da.MissingSchemaAction = MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey;
    conn.Close();
}
```

Comment: thanks for answer, yes this is something I'm looking for. Sorry for all missunderstandings, but I didn't post all my code to clarify myself better. I will do that, but for now I will try to use your suggestion, and tell you results.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but It doesn't work. When I try to set e.g. `DataAdapter1.UpdateCommand= InitCommand(ins_upd, shouldDelete: false);` I get error **Cannot implicitly convert void to oracle command**.

Comment: I updated my whole code for initializing DataAdapter, now you can see It. Only thing missing is that I also use switch statement for initializing same things for diferent tables, so whole code is very long, and I want to shorten It with passing parameter **DELETE_IN** value, as mentioned.